# Android DatabaseObjectNotClosedException on getReadableDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to use a SQLite db in my android app. It used to work ( and I swear I didn't change anything ), and clearly something changed, as my code now does not return anything upon querying the db. As I stepped through the code itself, I noticed that as soon as my DBHelper called `this.getReadableDatabase()` the database had a `mStackTrace` of DatabaseObjectNotClosedException, even though it is the first time I have ever opened the db in the app itself. Strangely enough, this error is never actually thrown, and it may not even be my problem, but I think it is a good place to start.

Code:
         {snip}

I'm not 100% on what exactly is going on here. The class is supposed to copy the database from res/assets to the local data folder, and it appears to work, but the database either is incorrect, or ends up being pointed to the wrong thing, because no rows are ever returned. Thoughts?

Edit: Additional update; I took a look through the data/ dir where I am storing files, and I have found two separate databases, one in `files/` and one in `databases/`. `files/` has the correct DB with all data intact, and `databases/` is just a blank database setup for android. My code is supposed to call the database in `files/`, but perhaps it is not?

Edit: Solved. I found the problem, and it had nothing to do with my DBhelper. Apparently my cohort on the project edited a field that he shouldn't have for testing, and forgot to change it back. Turned out that the SQL call I was making was faulty.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: For what it's worth, I have had problems with the READ_ONLY flag in the past and the so called compatibility program that vendors have to go through. Try removing that and rerunning your stuff. It used to fail for me while openning the DB, with a access violation, and then never closed it and left the cursor open having my app burn in flames.

Comment: To clarify my last statement, the sqlite version the vendor used in one of their phones, always opened a transaction on the db, even in Read_only mode which caused the resulting behavior ... sucked.

Comment: @GregGiacovelli It didn't fix the problem, but it may have uncovered a deeper one - I now get a `sqlite_open_c2 failed` error, though it does not seem to affect anything.

Comment: Gotcha, sorry, well these other answers look promising, you might want to paste the logcat of the stacktrace into the question too for more context.

Comment: @Phill.Zitt This exception means that you have multiple `SQLiteDatabase` instances opened (probably because you have created multiple `SQLiteOpenHelper`s and haven't closed them. You can easily avoid this issue by making your `SQLiteOpenHelper` a singleton.

Comment: Also... if you're not using an `SQLiteOpenHelper`, then I would recommend doing so, because it abstracts out all of the tedious work that is required to open/setup your `SQLiteDatabase` for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Solved. I found the problem, and it had nothing to do with my DBhelper. Apparently my cohort on the project edited a field that he shouldn't have for testing, and forgot to change it back. Turned out that the SQL call I was making was faulty. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are only ever working with one instance of `SQLiteOpenHelper`, as described in this [**blog post**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html). I'm betting the problem is that you have created multiple instances of the class accidentally and have forgotten to close one of them. You could also do what Sam suggests and be very careful to close the `SQLiteOpenHelper` instances that you create. However, in my opinion it is much cleaner to work with the same `SQLiteOpenHelper` across the entire application's lifecycle.

Comment: I did not think of that, actually, but I do not think that this would cause the problem I am having. I have only one member variable of the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class in a single activity ( no others ), and it is closed before the activity moves on.